# What characters can be used for up/down triangle (arrow without stem) for display in HTML?

Tags: html, css, unicode, icons, symbols

I'm looking for a **HTML** or **ASCII** character which is a triangle pointing up or down so that I can use it as a toggle switch.

I found ↑ (`&uarr;`), and ↓ (`&darr;`) - but those have a narrow stem. I'm looking just for the HTML arrow "head".

Comment: You could use the carat "^" (that's shift-6) and lower case "v" if you want to keep things simple.  Depending on the font you specify, they'll look like arrows.

Comment: check out this website for more ASCII character [http://graphemica.com/characters](http://graphemica.com/characters)

Comment: @mateusmaso - [Those](http://graphemica.com/characters)'re Unicode.

Comment: Here's a quick way to find them on one page: http://amp-what.com/#q=triangle

Comment: You can find a lot in this useful link , [Check all here]( http://www.integracoustics.com/MUG/MUG/bbs/characters.htm)

Comment: Go to search and look up "triangle" http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/index.htm, http://nwmtwd.com/misc_character_sets.html here the triangles are missing, but it's an useful summery.

Comment: Here's someone who took the trouble to gather up every possible Unicode arrow: http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_arrows.html

Comment: just a little typo correction: ^ is  *caret*, not *carat*

Comment: I know this may sound trivial, but a small /\, \/ looked really good in my case.

Comment: I use this as a DrowDown symbol: ˅ (Modifier Letter Down Arrowhead - Unicode number: U+02C5, HTML-code: &#709;)

Comment: This is also relevant as a Symbol for scrolling up and down (that's what I was looking for)

Comment: [AmpWhat](https://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/arrow) is your friend!

Answer (score 1780, accepted):

Unicode arrows heads:

- ▲ - U+25B2 BLACK UP-POINTING TRIANGLE
- ▼ - U+25BC BLACK DOWN-POINTING TRIANGLE
- ▴ - U+25B4 SMALL BLACK UP-POINTING TRIANGLE
- ▾ - U+25BE SMALL BLACK DOWN-POINTING TRIANGLE

For ▲ and ▼ use `&#x25B2;` and `&#x25BC;` respectively if you cannot include Unicode characters directly (use UTF-8!).

Note that the font support for the smaller versions is not as good. Better to use the large versions in smaller font.

More Unicode arrows are at:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_%28symbol%29#Arrows_in_Unicode
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Shapes

Lastly, these arrows are not ASCII, including ↑ and ↓: they are Unicode.

Comment: Also, to complete the first set (up down left right - ▲▼◀▼), left is U+25C0 and right is U+25B6. I found these here: http://www.unicode.org/charts/

Comment: "Unicode triangles." Just wanted to say that for Google's sake. :)

Comment: unicode chars rock! btw, here is the right triangle: ▶ another useful resource might be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Shapes

Comment: Yes, though ◀/▶ are less well-supported in fonts/fallback than ▲/▼... typically IE6 users will see squares. The left/right ‘pointer’ characters ◄/► are slightly more widely-supported though still not as common as up/down.

Comment: Another note: To add these in CSS you just use the numeric part with a backslash in front, ie .example { content: "\25B2"; }

Answer (score 714):

**For HTML Entities**   
◄ = `&#9668;` 
► = `&#9658;` 
▼ = `&#9660;` 
▲ = `&#9650;`

Answer (score 652):

### OPTION 1: UNICODE COLUMN SORT ARROWS

I found this one very handy for a single character column sorter.

*(Looks good upscaled)*

`&#x21D5;` = ⇕

[image: Unicode table column sort arrows]

> **IMPORTANT NOTE** *(When using Unicode symbols)*
>
> Unicode support varies dependant on the symbol of choice, browser and
> the font family. If you find your chosen symbol does not work in some
> browsers then try using a different font-family. Microsoft recommends
> `"Segoe UI Symbol"` however it would be wise to include the font with
> your website as not many people have it on their computers.

**Open this page in other browsers to see which symbols render with the default font.**

---

#### Some more unicode arrows.

To use them:

1. Copy them right off the page.
2. Use the code above each row inserting the corresponding hexadeximal number before the closing semi-colon relating to it's poition in the  row.

**Last Digit**

```
 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F
```

---

**`&#x219;`**

## ←   ↑   →   ↓   ↔   ↕   ↖   ↗   ↘   ↙   ↚   ↛   ↜   ↝   ↞   ↟

___

**`&#x21A;`**

## ↠   ↡   ↢   ↣   ↤   ↥   ↦   ↧   ↨   ↩   ↪   ↫   ↬   ↭   ↮   ↯

___

**`&#x21B;`**

## ↰   ↱   ↲   ↳   ↴   ↵   ↶   ↷   ↸   ↹   ↺   ↻   ↼   ↽   ↾   ↿

___

**`&#x21C;`**

## ⇀   ⇁   ⇂   ⇃   ⇄   ⇅   ⇆   ⇇   ⇈   ⇉   ⇊   ⇋   ⇌   ⇍   ⇎   ⇏

___

**`&#x21D;`**

## ⇐   ⇑   ⇒   ⇓   ⇔   ⇕   ⇖   ⇗   ⇘   ⇙   ⇚   ⇛   ⇜   ⇝   ⇞   ⇟

___

**`&#x21E;`**

## ⇠   ⇡   ⇢   ⇣   ⇤   ⇥   ⇦   ⇧   ⇨   ⇩   ⇪   ⇫   ⇬   ⇭   ⇮   ⇯

___

**`&#x21F;`**

## ⇰   ⇱   ⇲   ⇳   ⇴   ⇵   ⇶   ⇷   ⇸   ⇹   ⇺   ⇻   ⇼   ⇽   ⇾   ⇿

___

**Additional HTML unicode symbols**

A selected list of other helpful Unicode icons/symbols.

```
U+2302  ⌂   HOUSE
U+2303  ⌃   UP ARROWHEAD
U+2304  ⌄   DOWN ARROWHEAD
U+2305  ⌅   PROJECTIVE
U+2306  ⌆   PERSPECTIVE
U+2307  ⌇   WAVY LINE
U+2315  ⌕   TELEPHONE RECORDER
U+2316  ⌖   POSITION INDICATOR
U+2317  ⌗   VIEWDATA SQUARE
U+2318  ⌘   PLACE OF INTEREST SIGN
U+231A  ⌚   WATCH
U+231B  ⌛   HOURGLASS
U+2326  ⌦   ERASE TO THE RIGHT
U+2327  ⌧   X IN A RECTANGLE BOX
U+2328  ⌨   KEYBOARD
U+2329  〈   LEFT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET
U+232A  〉   RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET
U+232B  ⌫   ERASE TO THE LEFT
U+23E9  ⏩   BLACK RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE TRIANGLE
U+23EA  ⏪   BLACK LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE TRIANGLE
U+23EB  ⏫   BLACK UP-POINTING DOUBLE TRIANGLE
U+23EC  ⏬   BLACK DOWN-POINTING DOUBLE TRIANGLE
U+23ED  ⏭   BLACK RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE TRIANGLE WITH VERTICAL BAR
U+23EE  ⏮   BLACK LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE TRIANGLE WITH VERTICAL BAR
U+23EF  ⏯   BLACK RIGHT-POINTING TRIANGLE WITH DOUBLE VERTICAL BAR
U+23F0  ⏰   ALARM CLOCK
U+23F1  ⏱   STOPWATCH
U+23F2  ⏲   TIMER CLOCK
U+23F3  ⏳   HOURGLASS WITH FLOWING SAND
U+2600  ☀   BLACK SUN WITH RAYS
U+2601  ☁   CLOUD
U+2602  ☂   UMBRELLA
U+2603  ☃   SNOWMAN
U+2604  ☄   COMET
U+2605  ★   BLACK STAR
U+2606  ☆   WHITE STAR
U+2607  ☇   LIGHTNING
U+2608  ☈   THUNDERSTORM
U+2609  ☉   SUN
U+260A  ☊   ASCENDING NODE
U+260B  ☋   DESCENDING NODE
U+260C  ☌   CONJUNCTION
U+260D  ☍   OPPOSITION
U+260E  ☎   BLACK TELEPHONE
U+260F  ☏   WHITE TELEPHONE
U+2610  ☐   BALLOT BOX
U+2611  ☑   BALLOT BOX WITH CHECK
U+2612  ☒   BALLOT BOX WITH X
U+2613  ☓   SALTIRE
U+2614  ☔   UMBRELLA WITH RAINDROPS
U+2615  ☕   HOT BEVERAGE
U+2616  ☖   WHITE SHOGI PIECE
U+2617  ☗   BLACK SHOGI PIECE
U+2618  ☘   SHAMROCK
U+2619  ☙   REVERSED ROTATED FLORAL HEART BULLET
U+261A  ☚   BLACK LEFT-POINTING INDEX
U+261B  ☛   BLACK RIGHT-POINTING INDEX
U+261C  ☜   WHITE LEFT POINTING INDEX
U+261D  ☝   WHITE UP POINTING INDEX
U+261E  ☞   WHITE RIGHT POINTING INDEX
U+261F  ☟   WHITE DOWN POINTING INDEX
U+2620  ☠   SKULL AND CROSSBONES
U+2621  ☡   CAUTION SIGN
U+2622  ☢   RADIOACTIVE SIGN
U+2623  ☣   BIOHAZARD SIGN
U+262A  ☪   STAR AND CRESCENT
U+262B  ☫   FARSI SYMBOL
U+262C  ☬   ADI SHAKTI
U+262D  ☭   HAMMER AND SICKLE
U+262E  ☮   PEACE SYMBOL
U+262F  ☯   YIN YANG
U+2638  ☸   WHEEL OF DHARMA
U+2639  ☹   WHITE FROWNING FACE
U+263A  ☺   WHITE SMILING FACE
U+263B  ☻   BLACK SMILING FACE
U+263C  ☼   WHITE SUN WITH RAYS
U+263D  ☽   FIRST QUARTER MOON
U+263E  ☾   LAST QUARTER MOON
U+263F  ☿   MERCURY
U+2640  ♀   FEMALE SIGN
U+2641  ♁   EARTH
U+2642  ♂   MALE SIGN
U+2643  ♃   JUPITER
U+2644  ♄   SATURN
U+2645  ♅   URANUS
U+2646  ♆   NEPTUNE
U+2647  ♇   PLUTO
U+2648  ♈   ARIES
U+2649  ♉   TAURUS
U+264A  ♊   GEMINI
U+264B  ♋   CANCER
U+264C  ♌   LEO
U+264D  ♍   VIRGO
U+264E  ♎   LIBRA
U+264F  ♏   SCORPIUS
U+2650  ♐   SAGITTARIUS
U+2651  ♑   CAPRICORN
U+2652  ♒   AQUARIUS
U+2653  ♓   PISCES
U+2654  ♔   WHITE CHESS KING
U+2655  ♕   WHITE CHESS QUEEN
U+2656  ♖   WHITE CHESS ROOK
U+2657  ♗   WHITE CHESS BISHOP
U+2658  ♘   WHITE CHESS KNIGHT
U+2659  ♙   WHITE CHESS PAWN
U+265A  ♚   BLACK CHESS KING
U+265B  ♛   BLACK CHESS QUEEN
U+265C  ♜   BLACK CHESS ROOK
U+265D  ♝   BLACK CHESS BISHOP
U+265E  ♞   BLACK CHESS KNIGHT
U+265F  ♟   BLACK CHESS PAWN
U+2660  ♠   BLACK SPADE SUIT
U+2661  ♡   WHITE HEART SUIT
U+2662  ♢   WHITE DIAMOND SUIT
U+2663  ♣   BLACK CLUB SUITE
U+2664  ♤   WHITE SPADE SUIT
U+2665  ♥   BLACK HEART SUIT
U+2666  ♦   BLACK DIAMOND SUIT
U+2667  ♧   WHITE CLUB SUITE
U+2668  ♨   HOT SPRINGS
U+2669  ♩   QUARTER NOTE
U+266A  ♪   EIGHTH NOTE
U+266B  ♫   BEAMED EIGHTH NOTES
U+266C  ♬   BEAMED SIXTEENTH NOTES
U+266D  ♭   MUSIC FLAT SIGN
U+266E  ♮   MUSIC NATURAL SIGN
U+266F  ♯   MUSIC SHARP SIGN
U+267A  ♺   RECYCLING SYMBOL FOR GENERIC MATERIALS
U+267B  ♻   BLACK UNIVERSAL RECYCLING SYMBOL
U+267C  ♼   RECYCLED PAPER SYMBOL
U+267D  ♽   PARTIALLY-RECYCLED PAPER SYMBOL
U+267E  ♾   PERMANENT PAPER SIGN
U+267F  ♿   WHEELCHAIR SYMBOL
U+2680  ⚀   DIE FACE-1
U+2681  ⚁   DIE FACE-2
U+2682  ⚂   DIE FACE-3
U+2683  ⚃   DIE FACE-4
U+2684  ⚄   DIE FACE-5
U+2685  ⚅   DIE FACE-6
U+2686  ⚆   WHITE CIRCLE WITH DOT RIGHT
U+2687  ⚇   WHITE CIRCLE WITH TWO DOTS
U+2688  ⚈   BLACK CIRCLE WITH WHITE DOT RIGHT
U+2689  ⚉   BLACK CIRCLE WITH TWO WHITE DOTS
U+268A  ⚊   MONOGRAM FOR YANG
U+268B  ⚋   MONOGRAM FOR YIN
U+268C  ⚌   DIGRAM FOR GREATER YANG
U+268D  ⚍   DIGRAM FOR LESSER YIN
U+268E  ⚎   DIGRAM FOR LESSER YANG
U+268F  ⚏   DIGRAM FOR GREATER YIN
U+2690  ⚐   WHITE FLAG
U+2691  ⚑   BLACK FLAG
U+2692  ⚒   HAMMER AND PICK
U+2693  ⚓   ANCHOR
U+2694  ⚔   CROSSED SWORDS
U+2695  ⚕   STAFF OF AESCULAPIUS
U+2696  ⚖   SCALES
U+2697  ⚗   ALEMBIC
U+2698  ⚘   FLOWER
U+2699  ⚙   GEAR
U+269A  ⚚   STAFF OF HERMES
U+269B  ⚛   ATOM SYMBOL
U+269C  ⚜   FLEUR-DE-LIS
U+269D  ⚝   OUTLINED WHITE STAR
U+269E  ⚞   THREE LINES CONVERGING RIGHT
U+269F  ⚟   THREE LINES CONVERGING LEFT
U+26A0  ⚠   WARNING SIGN
U+26A1  ⚡   HIGH VOLTAGE SIGN
U+26A2  ⚢   DOUBLED FEMALE SIGN
U+26A3  ⚣   DOUBLED MALE SIGN
U+26A4  ⚤   INTERLOCKED FEMALE AND MALE SIGN
U+26A5  ⚥   MALE AND FEMALE SIGN
U+26A6  ⚦   MALE WITH STROKE SIGN
U+26A7  ⚧   MALE WITH STROKE AND MALE AND FEMALE SIGN
U+26A8  ⚨   VERTICAL MALE WITH STROKE SIGN
U+26A9  ⚩   HORIZONTAL MALE WITH STROKE SIGN
U+26AA  ⚪   MEDIUM WHITE CIRCLE
U+26AB  ⚫   MEDIUM BLACK CIRCLE
U+26BD  ⚽   SOCCER BALL
U+26BE  ⚾   BASEBALL
U+26BF  ⚿   SQUARED KEY
U+26C0  ⛀   WHITE DRAUGHTSMAN
U+26C1  ⛁   WHITE DRAUGHTS KING
U+26C2  ⛂   BLACK DRAUGHTSMAN
U+26C3  ⛃   BLACK DRAUGHTS KING
U+26C4  ⛄   SNOWMAN WITHOUT SNOW
U+26C5  ⛅   SUN BEHIND CLOUD
U+26C6  ⛆   RAIN
U+26C7  ⛇   BLACK SNOWMAN
U+26C8  ⛈   THUNDER CLOUD AND RAIN
U+26C9  ⛉   TURNED WHITE SHOGI PIECE
U+26CA  ⛊   TURNED BLACK SHOGI PIECE
U+26CB  ⛋   WHITE DIAMOND IN SQUARE
U+26CC  ⛌   CROSSING LANES
U+26CD  ⛍   DISABLED CAR
U+26CE  ⛎   OPHIUCHUS
U+26CF  ⛏   PICK
U+26D0  ⛐   CAR SLIDING
U+26D1  ⛑   HELMET WITH WHITE CROSS
U+26D2  ⛒   CIRCLED CROSSING LANES
U+26D3  ⛓   CHAINS
U+26D4  ⛔   NO ENTRY
U+26D5  ⛕   ALTERNATE ONE-WAY LEFT WAY TRAFFIC
U+26D6  ⛖   BLACK TWO-WAY LEFT WAY TRAFFIC
U+26D7  ⛗   WHITE TWO-WAY LEFT WAY TRAFFIC
U+26D8  ⛘   BLACK LEFT LANE MERGE
U+26D9  ⛙   WHITE LEFT LANE MERGE
U+26DA  ⛚   DRIVE SLOW SIGN
U+26DB  ⛛   HEAVY WHITE DOWN-POINTING TRIANGLE
U+26DC  ⛜   LEFT CLOSED ENTRY
U+26DD  ⛝   SQUARED SALTIRE
U+26DE  ⛞   FALLING DIAGONAL IN WHITE CIRCLE IN BLACK SQUARE
U+26DF  ⛟   BLACK TRUCK
U+26E0  ⛠   RESTRICTED LEFT ENTRY-1
U+26E1  ⛡   RESTRICTED LEFT ENTRY-2
U+26E2  ⛢   ASTRONOMICAL SYMBOL FOR URANUS
U+26E3  ⛣   HEAVY CIRCLE WITH STROKE AND TWO DOTS ABOVE
U+26E4  ⛤   PENTAGRAM
U+26E5  ⛥   RIGHT-HANDED INTERLACED PENTAGRAM
U+26E6  ⛦   LEFT-HANDED INTERLACED PENTAGRAM
U+26E7  ⛧   INVERTED PENTAGRAM
U+26E8  ⛨   BLACK CROSS ON SHIELD
U+26E9  ⛩   SHINTO SHRINE
U+26EA  ⛪   CHURCH
U+26EB  ⛫   CASTLE
U+26EC  ⛬   HISTORIC SITE
U+26ED  ⛭   GEAR WITHOUT HUB
U+26EE  ⛮   GEAR WITH HANDLES
U+26EF  ⛯   MAP SYMBOL FOR LIGHTHOUSE
U+26F0  ⛰   MOUNTAIN
U+26F1  ⛱   UMBRELLA ON GROUND
U+26F2  ⛲   FOUNTAIN
U+26F3  ⛳   FLAG IN HOLE
U+26F4  ⛴   FERRY
U+26F5  ⛵   SAILBOAT
U+26F6  ⛶   SQUARE FOUR CORNERS
U+26F7  ⛷   SKIER
U+26F8  ⛸   ICE SKATE
U+26F9  ⛹   PERSON WITH BALL
U+26FA  ⛺   TENT
U+26FD  ⛽   FUEL PUMP
U+26FE  ⛾   CUP ON BLACK SQUARE
U+26FF  ⛿   WHITE FLAG WITH HORIZONTAL MIDDLE BLACK STRIPE
U+2701  ✁   UPPER BLADE SCISSORS
U+2702  ✂   BLACK SCISSORS
U+2703  ✃   LOWER BLADE SCISSORS
U+2704  ✄   WHITE SCISSORS
U+2705  ✅   WHITE HEAVY CHECK MARK
U+2706  ✆   TELEPHONE LOCATION SIGN
U+2707  ✇   TAPE DRIVE
U+2708  ✈   AIRPLANE
U+2709  ✉   ENVELOPE
U+270A  ✊   RAISED FIST
U+270B  ✋   RAISED HAND
U+270C  ✌   VICTORY HAND
U+270D  ✍   WRITING HAND
U+270E  ✎   LOWER RIGHT PENCIL
U+270F  ✏   PENCIL
U+2710  ✐   UPPER RIGHT PENCIL
U+2711  ✑   WHITE NIB
U+2712  ✒   BLACK NIB
U+2713  ✓   CHECK MARK
U+2714  ✔   HEAVY CHECK MARK
U+2715  ✕   MULTIPLICATION X
U+2716  ✖   HEAVY MULTIPLICATION X
U+2717  ✗   BALLOT X
U+2718  ✘   HEAVY BALLOT X
U+2719  ✙   OUTLINED GREEK CROSS
U+271A  ✚   HEAVY GREEK CROSS
U+271B  ✛   OPEN CENTRE CROSS
U+271C  ✜   HEAVY OPEN CENTRE CROSS
U+271D  ✝   LATIN CROSS
U+271E  ✞   SHADOWED WHITE LATIN CROSS
U+271F  ✟   OUTLINED LATIN CROSS
U+2720  ✠   MALTESE CROSS
U+2721  ✡   STAR OF DAVID
U+2722  ✢   FOUR TEARDROP-SPOKED ASTERISK
U+2723  ✣   FOUR BALLOON-SPOKED ASTERISK
U+2724  ✤   HEAVY FOUR BALLOON-SPOKED ASTERISK
U+2725  ✥   FOUR CLUB-SPOKED ASTERISK
U+2726  ✦   BLACK FOUR POINTED STAR
U+2727  ✧   WHITE FOUR POINTED STAR
U+2728  ✨   SPARKLES
U+2729  ✩   STRESS OUTLINED WHITE STAR
U+272A  ✪   CIRCLED WHITE STAR
U+272B  ✫   OPEN CENTRE BLACK STAR
U+272C  ✬   BLACK CENTRE WHITE STAR
U+272D  ✭   OUTLINED BLACK STAR
U+272E  ✮   HEAVY OUTLINED BLACK STAR
U+272F  ✯   PINWHEEL STAR
U+2730  ✰   SHADOWED WHITE STAR
U+2731  ✱   HEAVY ASTERISK
U+2732  ✲   OPEN CENTRE ASTERISK
U+2733  ✳   EIGHT SPOKED ASTERISK
U+2734  ✴   EIGHT POINTED BLACK STAR
U+2735  ✵   EIGHT POINTED PINWHEEL STAR
U+2736  ✶   SIX POINTED BLACK STAR
U+2737  ✷   EIGHT POINTED RECTILINEAR BLACK STAR
U+2738  ✸   HEAVY EIGHT POINTED RECTILINEAR BLACK STAR
U+2739  ✹   TWELVE POINTED BLACK STAR
U+273A  ✺   SIXTEEN POINTED ASTERISK
U+273B  ✻   TEARDROP-SPOKED ASTERISK
U+273C  ✼   OPEN CENTRE TEARDROP-SPOKED ASTERISK
U+273D  ✽   HEAVY TEARDROP-SPOKED ASTERISK
U+273E  ✾   SIX PETALLED BLACK AND WHITE FLORETTE
U+273F  ✿   BLACK FLORETTE
U+2740  ❀   WHITE FLORETTE
U+2741  ❁   EIGHT PETALLED OUTLINED BLACK FLORETTE
U+2742  ❂   CIRCLED OPEN CENTRE EIGHT POINTED STAR
U+2743  ❃   HEAVY TEARDROP-SPOKED PINWHEEL ASTERISK
U+2744  ❄   SNOWFLAKE
U+2745  ❅   TIGHT TRIFOLIATE SNOWFLAKE
U+2746  ❆   HEAVY CHEVRON SNOWFLAKE
U+2747  ❇   SPARKLE
U+2748  ❈   HEAVY SPARKLE
U+2749  ❉   BALLOON-SPOKED ASTERISK
U+274A  ❊   EIGHT TEARDROP-SPOKED PROPELLER ASTERISK
U+274B  ❋   HEAVY EIGHT TEARDROP-SPOKED PROPELLER ASTERISK
U+274C  ❌   CROSS MARK
U+274D  ❍   SHADOWED WHITE CIRCLE
U+274E  ❎   NEGATIVE SQUARED CROSS MARK
U+2753  ❓   BLACK QUESTION MARK ORNAMENT
U+2754  ❔   WHITE QUESTION MARK ORNAMENT
U+2755  ❕   WHITE EXCLAMATION MARK ORNAMENT
U+2756  ❖   BLACK DIAMOND MINUS WHITE X
U+2757  ❗   HEAVY EXCLAMATION MARK SYMBOL
U+275B  ❛   HEAVY SINGLE TURNED COMMA QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT
U+275C  ❜   HEAVY SINGLE COMMA QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT
U+275D  ❝   HEAVY DOUBLE TURNED COMMA QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT
U+275E  ❞   HEAVY DOUBLE COMMA QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT
U+275F  ❟   HEAVY LOW SINGLE COMMA QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT
U+2760  ❠   HEAVY LOW DOUBLE COMMA QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT
U+2761  ❡   CURVED STEM PARAGRAPH SIGN ORNAMENT
U+2762  ❢   HEAVY EXCLAMATION MARK ORNAMENT
U+2763  ❣   HEAVY HEART EXCLAMATION MARK ORNAMENT
U+2764  ❤   HEAVY BLACK HEART
U+2765  ❥   ROTATED HEAVY BLACK HEART BULLET
U+2766  ❦   FLORAL HEART
U+2767  ❧   ROTATED FLORAL HEART BULLET
U+276C  ❬   MEDIUM LEFT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT
U+276D  ❭   MEDIUM RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT
U+276E  ❮   HEAVY LEFT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT
U+276F  ❯   HEAVY RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT
U+2770  ❰   HEAVY LEFT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT
U+2771  ❱   HEAVY RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT
U+2794  ➔   HEAVY WIDE-HEADED RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+2795  ➕   HEAVY PLUS SIGN
U+2796  ➖   HEAVY MINUS SIGN
U+2797  ➗   HEAVY DIVISION SIGN
U+2798  ➘   HEAVY SOUTH EAST ARROW
U+2799  ➙   HEAVY RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+279A  ➚   HEAVY NORTH EAST ARROW
U+279B  ➛   DRAFTING POINT RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+279C  ➜   HEAVY ROUND-TIPPED RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+279D  ➝   TRIANGLE-HEADED RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+279E  ➞   HEAVY TRIANGLE-HEADED RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+279F  ➟   DASHED TRIANGLE-HEADED RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27A0  ➠   HEAVY DASHED TRIANGLE-HEADED RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27A1  ➡   BLACK RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27A2  ➢   THREE-D TOP-LIGHTED RIGHTWARDS ARROWHEAD
U+27A3  ➣   THREE-D BOTTOM-LIGHTED RIGHTWARDS ARROWHEAD
U+27A4  ➤   BLACK RIGHTWARDS ARROWHEAD
U+27A5  ➥   HEAVY BLACK CURVED DOWNWARDS AND RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27A6  ➦   HEAVY BLACK CURVED UPWARDS AND RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27A7  ➧   SQUAT BLACK RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27A8  ➨   HEAVY CONCAVE-POINTED BLACK RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27A9  ➩   RIGHT-SHADED WHITE RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27AA  ➪   LEFT-SHADED WHITE RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27AB  ➫   BACK-TILTED SHADOWED WHITE RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27AC  ➬   FRONT-TILTED SHADOWED WHITE RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27AD  ➭   HEAVY LOWER RIGHT-SHADOWED WHITE RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27AE  ➮   HEAVY UPPER RIGHT-SHADOWED WHITE RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27AF  ➯   NOTCHED LOWER RIGHT-SHADOWED WHITE RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27B0  ➰   CURLY LOOP
U+27B1  ➱   NOTCHED UPPER RIGHT-SHADOWED WHITE RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27B2  ➲   CIRCLED HEAVY WHITE RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27B3  ➳   WHITE-FEATHERED RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27B4  ➴   BLACK-FEATHERED SOUTH EAST ARROW
U+27B5  ➵   BLACK-FEATHERED RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27B6  ➶   BLACK-FEATHERED NORTH EAST ARROW
U+27B7  ➷   HEAVY BLACK-FEATHERED SOUTH EAST ARROW
U+27B8  ➸   HEAVY BLACK-FEATHERED RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27B9  ➹   HEAVY BLACK-FEATHERED NORTH EAST ARROW
U+27BA  ➺   TEARDROP-BARBED RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27BB  ➻   HEAVY TEARDROP-SHANKED RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27BC  ➼   WEDGE-TAILED RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27BD  ➽   HEAVY WEDGE-TAILED RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27BE  ➾   OPEN-OUTLINED RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27C0  ⟀   THREE DIMENSIONAL ANGLE
U+27E8  ⟨   MATHEMATICAL LEFT ANGLE BRACKET
U+27E9  ⟩   MATHEMATICAL RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET
U+27EA  ⟪   MATHEMATICAL LEFT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET
U+27EB  ⟫   MATHEMATICAL RIGHT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET
U+27F0  ⟰   UPWARDS QUADRUPLE ARROW
U+27F1  ⟱   DOWNWARDS QUADRUPLE ARROW
U+27F2  ⟲   ANTICLOCKWISE GAPPED CIRCLE ARROW
U+27F3  ⟳   CLOCKWISE GAPPED CIRCLE ARROW
U+27F4  ⟴   RIGHT ARROW WITH CIRCLED PLUS
U+27F5  ⟵   LONG LEFTWARDS ARROW
U+27F6  ⟶   LONG RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+27F7  ⟷   LONG LEFT RIGHT ARROW
U+27F8  ⟸   LONG LEFTWARDS DOUBLE ARROW
U+27F9  ⟹   LONG RIGHTWARDS DOUBLE ARROW
U+27FA  ⟺   LONG LEFT RIGHT DOUBLE ARROW
U+27FB  ⟻   LONG LEFTWARDS ARROW FROM BAR
U+27FC  ⟼   LONG RIGHTWARDS ARROW FROM BAR
U+27FD  ⟽   LONG LEFTWARDS DOUBLE ARROW FROM BAR
U+27FE  ⟾   LONG RIGHTWARDS DOUBLE ARROW FROM BAR
U+27FF  ⟿   LONG RIGHTWARDS SQUIGGLE ARROW
U+2900  ⤀   RIGHTWARDS TWO-HEADED ARROW WITH VERTICAL STROKE
U+2901  ⤁   RIGHTWARDS TWO-HEADED ARROW WITH DOUBLE VERTICAL STROKE
U+2902  ⤂   LEFTWARDS DOUBLE ARROW WITH VERTICAL STROKE
U+2903  ⤃   RIGHTWARDS DOUBLE ARROW WITH VERTICAL STROKE
U+2904  ⤄   LEFT RIGHT DOUBLE ARROW WITH VERTICAL STROKE
U+2905  ⤅   RIGHTWARDS TWO-HEADED ARROW FROM BAR
U+2906  ⤆   LEFTWARDS DOUBLE ARROW FROM BAR
U+2907  ⤇   RIGHTWARDS DOUBLE ARROW FROM BAR
U+2908  ⤈   DOWNWARDS ARROW WITH HORIZONTAL STROKE
U+2909  ⤉   UPWARDS ARROW WITH HORIZONTAL STROKE
U+290A  ⤊   UPWARDS TRIPLE ARROW
U+290B  ⤋   DOWNWARDS TRIPLE ARROW
U+290C  ⤌   LEFTWARDS DOUBLE DASH ARROW
U+290D  ⤍   RIGHTWARDS DOUBLE DASH ARROW
U+290E  ⤎   LEFTWARDS TRIPLE DASH ARROW
U+290F  ⤏   RIGHTWARDS TRIPLE DASH ARROW
U+2910  ⤐   RIGHTWARDS TWO-HEADED TRIPLE DASH ARROW
U+2911  ⤑   RIGHTWARDS ARROW WITH DOTTED STEM
U+2912  ⤒   UPWARDS ARROW TO BAR
U+2913  ⤓   DOWNWARDS ARROW TO BAR
U+2914  ⤔   RIGHTWARDS ARROW WITH TAIL WITH VERTICAL STROKE
U+2915  ⤕   RIGHTWARDS ARROW WITH TAIL WITH DOUBLE VERTICAL STROKE
U+2916  ⤖   RIGHTWARDS TWO-HEADED ARROW WITH TAIL
U+2917  ⤗   RIGHTWARDS TWO-HEADED ARROW WITH TAIL WITH VERTICAL STROKE
U+2918  ⤘   RIGHTWARDS TWO-HEADED ARROW WITH TAIL WITH DOUBLE VERTICAL STROKE
U+2919  ⤙   LEFTWARDS ARROW-TAIL
U+291A  ⤚   RIGHTWARDS ARROW-TAIL
U+291B  ⤛   LEFTWARDS DOUBLE ARROW-TAIL
U+291C  ⤜   RIGHTWARDS DOUBLE ARROW-TAIL
U+291D  ⤝   LEFTWARDS ARROW TO BLACK DIAMOND
U+291E  ⤞   RIGHTWARDS ARROW TO BLACK DIAMOND
U+291F  ⤟   LEFTWARDS ARROW FROM BAR TO BLACK DIAMOND
U+2920  ⤠   RIGHTWARDS ARROW FROM BAR TO BLACK DIAMOND
U+2921  ⤡   NORTHWEST AND SOUTH EAST ARROW
U+2922  ⤢   NORTHEAST AND SOUTH WEST ARROW
U+2923  ⤣   NORTH WEST ARROW WITH HOOK
U+2924  ⤤   NORTH EAST ARROW WITH HOOK
U+2925  ⤥   SOUTH EAST ARROW WITH HOOK
U+2926  ⤦   SOUTH WEST ARROW WITH HOOK
U+2927  ⤧   NORTH WEST ARROW AND NORTH EAST ARROW
U+2928  ⤨   NORTH EAST ARROW AND SOUTH EAST ARROW
U+2929  ⤩   SOUTH EAST ARROW AND SOUTH WEST ARROW
U+292A  ⤪   SOUTH WEST ARROW AND NORTH WEST ARROW
U+292B  ⤫   RISING DIAGONAL CROSSING FALLING DIAGONAL
U+292C  ⤬   FALLING DIAGONAL CROSSING RISING DIAGONAL
U+292D  ⤭   SOUTH EAST ARROW CROSSING NORTH EAST ARROW
U+292E  ⤮   NORTH EAST ARROW CROSSING SOUTH EAST ARROW
U+292F  ⤯   FALLING DIAGONAL CROSSING NORTH EAST ARROW
U+2930  ⤰   RISING DIAGONAL CROSSING SOUTH EAST ARROW
U+2931  ⤱   NORTH EAST ARROW CROSSING NORTH WEST ARROW
U+2932  ⤲   NORTH WEST ARROW CROSSING NORTH EAST ARROW
U+2933  ⤳   WAVE ARROW POINTING DIRECTLY RIGHT
U+2934  ⤴   ARROW POINTING RIGHTWARDS THEN CURVING UPWARDS
U+2935  ⤵   ARROW POINTING RIGHTWARDS THEN CURVING DOWNWARDS
U+2936  ⤶   ARROW POINTING DOWNWARDS THEN CURVING LEFTWARDS
U+2937  ⤷   ARROW POINTING DOWNWARDS THEN CURVING RIGHTWARDS
U+2938  ⤸   RIGHT-SIDE ARC CLOCKWISE ARROW
U+2939  ⤹   LEFT-SIDE ARC ANTICLOCKWISE ARROW
U+293A  ⤺   TOP ARC ANTICLOCKWISE ARROW
U+293B  ⤻   BOTTOM ARC ANTICLOCKWISE ARROW
U+293C  ⤼   TOP ARC CLOCKWISE ARROW WITH MINUS
U+293D  ⤽   TOP ARC ANTICLOCKWISE ARROW WITH PLUS
U+293E  ⤾   LOWER RIGHT SEMICIRCULAR CLOCKWISE ARROW
U+293F  ⤿   LOWER LEFT SEMICIRCULAR ANTICLOCKWISE ARROW
U+2940  ⥀   ANTICLOCKWISE CLOSED CIRCLE ARROW
U+2941  ⥁   CLOCKWISE CLOSED CIRCLE ARROW
U+2942  ⥂   RIGHTWARDS ARROW ABOVE SHORT LEFTWARDS ARROW
U+2943  ⥃   LEFTWARDS ARROW ABOVE SHORT RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+2944  ⥄   SHORT RIGHTWARDS ARROW ABOVE LEFTWARDS ARROW
U+2945  ⥅   RIGHTWARDS ARROW WITH PLUS BELOW
U+2946  ⥆   LEFTWARDS ARROW WITH PLUS BELOW
U+2962  ⥢   LEFTWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB UP ABOVE LEFTWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB DOWN
U+2963  ⥣   UPWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB LEFT BESIDE UPWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB RIGHT
U+2964  ⥤   RIGHTWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB UP ABOVE RIGHTWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB DOWN
U+2965  ⥥   DOWNWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB LEFT BESIDE DOWNWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB RIGHT
U+2966  ⥦   LEFTWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB UP ABOVE RIGHTWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB UP
U+2967  ⥧   LEFTWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB DOWN ABOVE RIGHTWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB DOWN
U+2968  ⥨   RIGHTWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB UP ABOVE LEFTWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB UP
U+2969  ⥩   RIGHTWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB DOWN ABOVE LEFTWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB DOWN
U+296A  ⥪   LEFTWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB UP ABOVE LONG DASH
U+296B  ⥫   LEFTWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB DOWN BELOW LONG DASH
U+296C  ⥬   RIGHTWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB UP ABOVE LONG DASH
U+296D  ⥭   RIGHTWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB DOWN BELOW LONG DASH
U+296E  ⥮   UPWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB LEFT BESIDE DOWNWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB RIGHT
U+296F  ⥯   DOWNWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB LEFT BESIDE UPWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB RIGHT
U+2989  ⦉   Z NOTATION LEFT BINDING BRACKET
U+298A  ⦊   Z NOTATION RIGHT BINDING BRACKET
U+2991  ⦑   LEFT ANGLE BRACKET WITH DOT
U+2992  ⦒   RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET WITH DOT
U+2993  ⦓   LEFT ARC LESS-THAN BRACKET
U+2994  ⦔   RIGHT ARC GREATER-THAN BRACKET
U+2995  ⦕   DOUBLE LEFT ARC GREATER-THAN BRACKET
U+2996  ⦖   DOUBLE RIGHT ARC LESS-THAN BRACKET
U+29A8  ⦨   MEASURED ANGLE WITH OPEN ARM ENDING IN ARROW POINTING UP AND RIGHT
U+29A9  ⦩   MEASURED ANGLE WITH OPEN ARM ENDING IN ARROW POINTING UP AND LEFT
U+29AA  ⦪   MEASURED ANGLE WITH OPEN ARM ENDING IN ARROW POINTING DOWN AND RIGHT
U+29AB  ⦫   MEASURED ANGLE WITH OPEN ARM ENDING IN ARROW POINTING DOWN AND LEFT
U+29AC  ⦬   MEASURED ANGLE WITH OPEN ARM ENDING IN ARROW POINTING RIGHT AND UP
U+29AD  ⦭   MEASURED ANGLE WITH OPEN ARM ENDING IN ARROW POINTING LEFT AND UP
U+29AE  ⦮   MEASURED ANGLE WITH OPEN ARM ENDING IN ARROW POINTING RIGHT AND DOWN
U+29AF  ⦯   MEASURED ANGLE WITH OPEN ARM ENDING IN ARROW POINTING LEFT AND DOWN
U+29BE  ⦾   CIRCLED WHITE BULLET
U+29BF  ⦿   CIRCLED BULLET
U+29C9  ⧉   TWO JOINED SQUARES
U+29CE  ⧎   RIGHT TRIANGLE ABOVE LEFT TRIANGLE
U+29CF  ⧏   LEFT TRIANGLE BESIDE VERTICAL BAR
U+29D0  ⧐   VERTICAL BAR BESIDE RIGHT TRIANGLE
U+29D1  ⧑   BOWTIE WITH LEFT HALF BLACK
U+29D2  ⧒   BOWTIE WITH RIGHT HALF BLACK
U+29D3  ⧓   BLACK BOWTIE
U+29D4  ⧔   TIMES WITH LEFT HALF BLACK
U+29D5  ⧕   TIMES WITH RIGHT HALF BLACK
U+29D6  ⧖   WHITE HOURGLASS
U+29D7  ⧗   BLACK HOURGLASS
U+29E8  ⧨   DOWN-POINTING TRIANGLE WITH LEFT HALF BLACK
U+29E9  ⧩   DOWN-POINTING TRIANGLE WITH RIGHT HALF BLACK
U+29EA  ⧪   BLACK DIAMOND WITH DOWN ARROW
U+29EB  ⧫   BLACK LOZENGE
U+29EC  ⧬   WHITE CIRCLE WITH DOWN ARROW
U+29ED  ⧭   BLACK CIRCLE WITH DOWN ARROW
U+29F4  ⧴   RULE-DELAYED
U+29FC  ⧼   LEFT-POINTING CURVED ANGLE BRACKET
U+29FD  ⧽   RIGHT-POINTING CURVED ANGLE BRACKET
U+29FE  ⧾   TINY
U+29FF  ⧿   MINY
U+2B00  ⬀   NORTH EAST WHITE ARROW
U+2B01  ⬁   NORTH WEST WHITE ARROW
U+2B02  ⬂   SOUTH EAST WHITE ARROW
U+2B03  ⬃   SOUTH WEST WHITE ARROW
U+2B04  ⬄   LEFT RIGHT WHITE ARROW
U+2B05  ⬅   LEFTWARDS BLACK ARROW
U+2B06  ⬆   UPWARDS BLACK ARROW
U+2B07  ⬇   DOWNWARDS BLACK ARROW
U+2B08  ⬈   NORTH EAST BLACK ARROW
U+2B09  ⬉   NORTH WEST BLACK ARROW
U+2B0A  ⬊   SOUTH EAST BLACK ARROW
U+2B0B  ⬋   SOUTHWEST BLACK ARROW
U+2B0C  ⬌   LEFT RIGHT BLACK ARROW
U+2B0D  ⬍   UP DOWN BLACK ARROW
U+2B0E  ⬎   RIGHTWARDS ARROW WITH TIP DOWNWARDS
U+2B0F  ⬏   RIGHTWARDS ARROW WITH TIP UPWARDS
U+2B10  ⬐   LEFTWARDS ARROW WITH TIP DOWNWARDS
U+2B11  ⬑   LEFTWARDS ARROW WITH TIP UPWARDS
U+2B12  ⬒   SQUARE WITH TOP HALF BLACK
U+2B13  ⬓   SQUARE WITH BOTTOM HALF BLACK
U+2B14  ⬔   SQUARE WITH UPPER RIGHT DIAGONAL HALF BLACK
U+2B15  ⬕   SQUARE WITH LOWER LEFT DIAGONAL HALF BLACK
U+2B16  ⬖   DIAMOND WITH LEFT HALF BLACK
U+2B17  ⬗   DIAMOND WITH RIGHT HALF BLACK
U+2B18  ⬘   DIAMOND WITH TOP HALF BLACK
U+2B19  ⬙   DIAMOND WITH BOTTOM HALF BLACK
U+2B1A  ⬚   DOTTED SQUARE
U+2B1B  ⬛   BLACK LARGE SQUARE
U+2B1C  ⬜   WHITE LARGE SQUARE
U+2B1D  ⬝   BLACK VERY SMALL SQUARE
U+2B1E  ⬞   WHITE VERY SMALL SQUARE
U+2B1F  ⬟   BLACK PENTAGON
U+2B20  ⬠   WHITE PENTAGON
U+2B21  ⬡   WHITE HEXAGON
U+2B22  ⬢   BLACK HEXAGON
U+2B23  ⬣   HORIZONTAL BLACK HEXAGON
U+2B24  ⬤   BLACK LARGE CIRCLE
U+2B25  ⬥   BLACK MEDIUM DIAMOND
U+2B26  ⬦   WHITE MEDIUM DIAMOND
U+2B27  ⬧   BLACK MEDIUM LOZENGE
U+2B28  ⬨   WHITE MEDIUM LOZENGE
U+2B29  ⬩   BLACK SMALL DIAMOND
U+2B2A  ⬪   BLACK SMALL LOZENGE
U+2B2B  ⬫   WHITE SMALL LOZENGE
U+2B30  ⬰   LEFT ARROW WITH SMALL CIRCLE
U+2B31  ⬱   THREE LEFTWARDS ARROWS
U+2B32  ⬲   LEFT ARROW WITH CIRCLED PLUS
U+2B33  ⬳   LONG LEFTWARDS SQUIGGLE ARROW
U+2B34  ⬴   LEFTWARDS TWO-HEADED ARROW WITH VERTICAL STROKE
U+2B35  ⬵   LEFTWARDS TWO-HEADED ARROW WITH DOUBLE VERTICAL STROKE
U+2B36  ⬶   LEFTWARDS TWO-HEADED ARROW FROM BAR
U+2B37  ⬷   LEFTWARDS TWO-HEADED TRIPLE DASH ARROW
U+2B38  ⬸   LEFTWARDS ARROW WITH DOTTED STEM
U+2B39  ⬹   LEFTWARDS ARROW WITH TAIL WITH VERTICAL STROKE
U+2B3A  ⬺   LEFTWARDS ARROW WITH TAIL WITH DOUBLE VERTICAL STROKE
U+2B3B  ⬻   LEFTWARDS TWO-HEADED ARROW WITH TAIL
U+2B3C  ⬼   LEFTWARDS TWO-HEADED ARROW WITH TAIL WITH VERTICAL STROKE
U+2B3D  ⬽   LEFTWARDS TWO-HEADED ARROW WITH TAIL WITH DOUBLE VERTICAL STROKE
U+2B3E  ⬾   LEFTWARDS ARROW THROUGH X
U+2B3F  ⬿   WAVE ARROW POINTING DIRECTLY LEFT
U+2B40  ⭀   EQUALS SIGN ABOVE LEFTWARDS ARROW
U+2B41  ⭁   REVERSE TILDE OPERATOR ABOVE LEFTWARDS ARROW
U+2B42  ⭂   LEFTWARDS ARROW ABOVE REVERSE ALMOST EQUAL TO
U+2B43  ⭃   RIGHTWARDS ARROW THROUGH GREATER-THAN
U+2B44  ⭄   RIGHTWARDS ARROW THROUGH SUPERSET
U+2B45  ⭅   LEFTWARDS QUADRUPLE ARROW
U+2B46  ⭆   RIGHTWARDS QUADRUPLE ARROW
U+2B47  ⭇   REVERSE TILDE OPERATOR ABOVE RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+2B48  ⭈   RIGHTWARDS ARROW ABOVE REVERSE ALMOST EQUAL TO
U+2B49  ⭉   TILDE OPERATOR ABOVE LEFTWARDS ARROW
U+2B4A  ⭊   LEFTWARDS ARROW ABOVE ALMOST EQUAL TO
U+2B4B  ⭋   LEFTWARDS ARROW ABOVE REVERSE TILDE OPERATOR
U+2B4C  ⭌   RIGHTWARDS ARROW ABOVE REVERSE TILDE OPERATOR
U+2B50  ⭐   WHITE MEDIUM STAR
U+2B51  ⭑   BLACK SMALL STAR
U+2B52  ⭒   WHITE SMALL STAR
U+2B53  ⭓   BLACK RIGHT-POINTING PENTAGON
U+2B54  ⭔   WHITE RIGHT-POINTING PENTAGON
U+2B55  ⭕   HEAVY LARGE CIRCLE
U+2B56  ⭖   HEAVY OVAL WITH OVAL INSIDE
U+2B57  ⭗   HEAVY CIRCLE WITH CIRCLE INSIDE
U+2B58  ⭘   HEAVY CIRCLE
U+2B59  ⭙   HEAVY CIRCLED SALTIRE
```

---

### OPTION 2: PURE CSS CHEVRONS

You can create the chevrons efficiently using only `CSS`

*(No images required).*

It's easy to manipulate:

- **ROTATION**
- **THICKNESS**
- **COLOR**
- **SIZE**

---

[<kbd>CLICK FOR DEMO ON JSFIDDLE</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/Ur6a7/)

---

[image]

---

**CSS**
*(Efficient with cross browser support)*

```css
.chevron {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 50px; /*height should be double border*/
}

.chevron::before,
.chevron::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  border: 25px solid transparent; /*adjust size*/
}

/* Replace all text `top` below with left/right/bottom to rotate the chevron */

.chevron::before {
  top: 0;
  border-top-color: #b00; /*Chevron Color*/
}

.chevron::after {
  top: -10px; /*adjust thickness*/
  border-top-color: #fff; /*Match background colour*/
}
```

```html
<i class="chevron"></i>
```

---

### OPTION 3: CSS BASE64 IMAGE ICONS

[image: UP/DOWN] **UP/DOWN**

[image: DOWN] **DOWN**

[image: UP] **UP**

Using only a few lines of CSS we can encode our images into base64.

---

[<kbd>CLICK FOR DEMO ON JSFIDDLE</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/m7zby2gw/)

---

**PROS**

- No need to include additional resources in the form of images or fonts.
- Supports full alpha transparency.
- Full cross-browser support.
- Small images/icons can be stored in a database.

**CONS**

- Updating/editing can become a hassle.
- Not suitable for large images due to excessive code markup that's generated.

**CSS**

```
.sorting,
.sorting_asc,
.sorting_desc{
    padding:4px 21px 4px 4px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.sorting{
    background:url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCwALAJEAAAAAAP///xUVFf///yH5BAEAAAMALAAAAAALAAsAAAIUnC2nKLnT4or00PvyrQwrPzUZshQAOw==) no-repeat center right;
}
.sorting_asc{
    background:url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCwALAJEAAAAAAP///xUVFf///yH5BAEAAAMALAAAAAALAAsAAAIRnC2nKLnT4or00Puy3rx7VQAAOw==) no-repeat center right;
}
.sorting_desc{
    background:url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCwALAJEAAAAAAP///xUVFf///yH5BAEAAAMALAAAAAALAAsAAAIPnI+py+0/hJzz0IruwjsVADs=) no-repeat center right;
}
```

Answer (score 301):

Sorry but they are only in Unicode. :(

Big ones:

- `U+25B2` (Black up-pointing triangle ▲)
- `U+25BC` (Black down-pointing triangle ▼)
- `U+25C0` (Black left-pointing triangle ◀)
- `U+25B6` (Black right-pointing triangle ▶)

Big white ones:

- `U+25B3` (White up-pointing triangle △)
- `U+25BD` (White down-pointing triangle ▽)
- `U+25C1` (White left-pointing triangle ◁)
- `U+25B7` (White right-pointing triangle ▷)

There is also some smalller triangles:

- `U+25B4` (Black up-pointing small triangle ▴)
- `U+25C2` (Black left-pointing small triangle ◂)
- `U+25BE` (Black down-pointing small triangle ▾)
- `U+25B8` (Black right-pointing small triangle ▸)

Also some white ones:

- `U+25C3` (White left-pointing small triangle ◃)
- `U+25BF` (White down-pointing small triangle ▿)
- `U+25B9` (White right-pointing small triangle ▹)
- `U+25B5` (White up-pointing small triangle ▵)

There are also some "pointy" triangles. You can read more here in Wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Shapes

But unfortunately, they are all Unicode instead of ASCII.
If you still want to use ASCII, then you can use an image file for it of just use `^` and `v`. (<strike>Just like the Google Maps in the mobile version</strike> this was referring to the *ancient* mobile Google Maps)

---

As others also suggested, you can also create triangles with HTML, either with CSS borders or SVG shapes or even JavaScript canvases.

### CSS

```
div{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 10px solid black;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

### SVG

```
<svg width="16" height="10">
    <polygon points="0,0 16,0 8,10"/>
</svg>
```

## JavaScript

```
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

// do not use with() outside of this demo!
with(ctx){
    beginPath();
    moveTo(0,0);
    lineTo(16,0);
    lineTo(8,10);
    fill();
    endPath();
}
```

### [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/t0z9vvw1/)

Answer (score 101):

There are literal arrowheads in the [*Spacing Modifier Letters*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacing_Modifier_Letters) block:

```
U+02C2  ˂   &#706;  Modifier Letter Left  Arrowhead
U+02C3  ˃   &#707;  Modifier Letter Right Arrowhead
U+02C4  ˄   &#708;  Modifier Letter Up    Arrowhead
U+02C5  ˅   &#709;  Modifier Letter Down  Arrowhead
```

Comment: This approach might be more useful for accessibility purposes for screen readers, etc.

Answer (score 94):

Since you're using these arrows for a toggle switch you may want to consider creating these arrows with an html element using the following styles instead of unicode characters.

```
.upparrow {
   height: 0;
   width: 0;
   border: 4px solid transparent;
   border-bottom-color: #000;
}

.downarrow {
   height: 0;
   width: 0;
   border: 4px solid transparent;
   border-top-color: #000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FrsGR/

Comment: The four borders of a square element meet at 45° angles so by only coloring one of the borders you end up with a triangle.


You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/FrsGR/

Answer (score 20):

There are several correct ways to display a down-pointing triangle.

### Method 1 : use decimal HTML entity

HTML :

```
&#9660;
```

---

### Method 2 : use hexidecimal HTML entity

HTML :

```
&#x25BC;
```

---

### Method 3 : use character directly

HTML :

```
▼
```

---

### Method 4 : use CSS

HTML :

```
<span class='icon-down'></span>
```

CSS :

```
.icon-down:before {
    content: "\25BC";
}
```

---

Each of these three methods should have the same output. For other symbols, the same three options exist. Some even have a fourth option, allowing you to use a string based reference (eg. `&hearts;` to display ♥).

You can use a reference website like **[Unicode-table.com](http://unicode-table.com/en/)** to find which icons are supported in UNICODE and which codes they correspond with. For example, you find the values for the down-pointing triangle at **http://unicode-table.com/en/25BC/**.

Note that these methods are sufficient only for icons that are available by default in every browser. For symbols like ☃,❄,★,☂,☭,⎗ or ⎘, this is far less likely to be the case. While it is possible to provide cross-browser support for other UNICODE symbols, the procedure is a bit more complicated.

If you want to know how to add support for less common UNICODE characters, see **[Create webfont with Unicode Supplementary Multilingual Plane symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824628/create-webfont-with-unicode-supplementary-multilingual-plane-symbols/27410391#27410391)** for more info on how to do this.

---

### Background images

A totally different strategy is the use of background-images instead of fonts. For optimal performance, it's best to embed the image in your CSS file by base-encoding it, as mentioned by eg. @weasel5i2 and @Obsidian. I would recommend the use of SVG rather than GIF, however, is that's better both for performance and for the sharpness of your symbols.

This following code is the base64 for and SVG version of the [image] icon :

```
/* size: 0.9kb */
url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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
```

### **When to use background-images or fonts**

For many use cases, SVG-based background images and icon fonts are largely equivalent with regards to performance and flexibility. To decide which to pick, consider the following differences:

**SVG images**

- They can have multiple colors
- They can embed their own CSS and/or be styled by the HTML document
- They can be loaded as a seperate file, embedded in CSS AND embedded in HTML
- Each symbol is represented by XML code or base64 code. You cannot use the character directly within your code editor or use an HTML entity
- Multiple uses of the same symbol implies duplication of the symbol when XML code is embedded in the HTML. Duplication is not required when embedding the file in the CSS or loading it as a seperate file
- You can not use `color`, `font-size`, `line-height`, `background-color` or other font related styling rules to change the display of your icon, but you can reference different components of the icon as shapes individually.
- You need some knowledge of SVG and/or base64 encoding
- Limited or no support in old versions of IE

**Icon fonts**

- An icon can have but one fill color, one background color, etc.
- An icon can be embedded in CSS or HTML. In HTML, you can use the character directly or use an HTML entity to represent it.
- Some symbols can be displayed without the use of a webfont. Most symbols cannot.
- Multiple uses of the same symbol implies duplication of the symbol when your character embedded in the HTML. Duplication is not required when embedding the file in the CSS.
- You can use `color`, `font-size`, `line-height`, `background-color` or other font related styling rules to change the display of your icon
- You need no special technical knowledge
- Support in all major browsers, including old versions of IE

Personally, I would recommend the use of background-images only when you need multiple colors and those color can't be achieved by means of `color`, `background-color` and other color-related CSS rules for fonts.

The main benefit of using SVG images is that you can give different components of a symbol their own styling. If you embed your SVG XML code in the HTML document, this is very similar to styling the HTML. This would, however, result in a web page that uses both HTML tags and SVG tags, which could significantly reduce the readability of a webpage. It also adds extra bloat if the symbol is repeated across multiple pages and you need to consider that old versions of IE have no or limited support for SVG.

Answer (score 17):

Usually, best is to see a character in his context.

Here is the **full list of Unicode chars**, and how your browser currently displays them. I am seeing this list evolving, browser versions after others.

This list is obtained by iteration in decimal of the html entities unicode table, it may take some seconds, but is very useful to me in many cases.

By hovering quickly a given char you will get the dec and hex and the shortcuts to generate it with a keyboard.

```js
var i = 0
    do document.write("<a title='(Linux|Hex): [CTRL+SHIFT]+u"+(i).toString(16)+"\nHtml entity: &# "+i+";\n&#x"+(i).toString(16)+";\n(Win|Dec): [ALT]+"+i+"' onmouseover='this.focus()' onclick='this.href=\"//google.com/?q=\"+this.innerHTML' style='cursor:pointer' target='new'>"+"&#"+i+";</a>"),i++
    while (i<136690)
window.stop() 


//  From https://codepen.io/Nico_KraZhtest/pen/mWzXqy
```

The same snippet as a bookmarklet:

```
javascript:void%20!function(){var%20t=0;do{document.write(%22%3Ca%20title='(Linux|Hex):%20[CTRL+SHIFT]+u%22+t.toString(16)+%22\nHtml%20entity:%20%26%23%20%22+t+%22;\n%26%23x%22+t.toString(16)+%22;\n(Win|Dec):%20[ALT]+%22+t+%22'%20onmouseover='this.focus()'%20onclick='this.href=\%22https://google.com/%3Fq=\%22+this.innerHTML'%20style='cursor:pointer'%20target='new'%3E%26%23%22+t+%22;%3C/a%3E%22),t++}while(t%3C136690);window.stop()}();
```

---

**To generate that list from php**:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < 136690; $x++) {
  echo html_entity_decode('&#'.$x.';',ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8');
}
```

**To generate that list into the console, using php**:

```
php -r 'for ($x = 0; $x < 136690; $x++) { echo html_entity_decode("&#".$x.";",ENT_NOQUOTES,"UTF-8");}'
```

---

Here is a plain text extract, of arrows, some are coming with **unicode 10.0**.
http://unicode.org/versions/Unicode10.0.0/

> Unicode 10.0 adds 8,518 characters, for a total of 136,690 characters.

**⭝⭞⭟⭠⭡⭢⭣⭤⭥⭦⭧⭨⭩⭪⭫⭬⭭⭮⭯⭰⭱⭲⭳⭶⭷⭸⭹⭺⭻⭼⭽⭾⭿⮀⮁⮂⮃⮄⮅⮆⮇⮈⮉⮊⮋⮌⮍⮎⮏⮐⮑⮒⮓⮔⮕⮘⮙⮚⮛⮜⮝⮞⮟⮠⮡⮢⮣⮤⮥⮦⮧⮨⮩⮪⮫⮬⮭⮮⮯⮰⮱⮲⮳⮴⮵⮶⮷⮸⮹⮽⮾⮿⯀⯁⯂⯅⯆⯇⯈⬶⬷⬸⬹⬺⬻⬼⬽⬾⬀⬁⬂⬃⬄⬅⬆⬇⬈⬉⬊⬋⬌⬍⬎⬏⬐⬑⤀⤁⤂⤃⤄⤅⤆⤇⤈⤉⤊⤋⤌⤍⤎⤏⤐⤑⤒⤓⤔⤕⤖⤗⤘⤙⤚⤛⤜⤝⤞⤟⤠⤡⤢⤣⤤⤥⤦⤧⤨⤩⤪⤫⤬⤭⤮⤯⤰⤱⤲⤳⤴⤵⤶⤷⤸⤹⤺⤻⤼⤽⤾⤿⥀⥁⥂⥃⥄⥅⥆⥇⥈⥉⥊⥋⥌⥍⥎⥏⥐⥑⥒⥓⥔⥕⥖⥗⥘⥙⥚⥛⥜⥝⥞⥟⥠⥡⥢⥣⥤⥥⥦⥧⥨⥩⥪⥫⥬⥭⥮⥯⥰⥱⥲⥳⥴⥵⟨⟩⟪⟫⟬⟭⟮⟯⟰⟱⟲⟳⟴⟵⟶⟷⟸⟹⟺⟻⟼⟽⟾⟿➘➙➚➛➜➝➞➟➠➡➢➣➤➥➦➧➨➩➪➫➬➭➮➯➰➱➲➳➴➵➶➷➸➹➺➻➼➽➾⊲⊳⊴⊵←↑→↓↔↕↖↗↘↙↚↛↜↝↞↟↠↡↢↣↤↥↦↧↨↩↪↫↬↭↮↯↰↱↲↳↴↵↶↷↸↹↺↻↼↽↾↿⇀⇁⇂⇃⇄⇅⇆⇇⇈⇉⇊⇋⇌⇍⇎⇏⇐⇑⇒⇓⇔⇕⇖⇗⇘⇙⇚⇛⇜⇝⇞⇟⇠⇡⇢⇣⇤⇥⇦⇧⇨⇩⇪⇫⇬⇭⇮⇯⇰⇱⇲⇳⇴⇵⇶⇷⇸⇹⇺⇻⇼⇽⇾⇿ᐂᐃᐄᐅᐆᐇᐈᐉᐊᐋᐌᐍᐎᐏᐐᐑᐒᐓᐔᐕᐖᐗᐘᐙᐚᐛᐫᐬᐭᐮᐯᐰᐱᐲᐳᐴᐵᐶᐷᐸᐹᐺᐻᐼᐽᐾᐿᑀᑁᑂᑃᑄᑅᑆᑇᑈ**

---

Hey, did you notice the plain html `<details>` element has a drop down arrow? This is sometimes all what we need.

```html
<details>
  <summary>Morning</summary>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
</details>
<details>
  <summary>Evening</summary>
  <p>How sweat?</p>
</details>
```

Comment: This looks helpful. Do you know how to tell whether Unicode 10 is supported in certain browsers? I checked https://caniuse.com/#search=unicode%2010, but it didn't seem to say.

Comment: Well, hard to say. For linux free browser like chromium, it isn't out of the box, but we can install additionnal fonts. The most complete is probably emojione: https://github.com/emojione/emojione

Answer (score 14):

"Not ASCII (neither's ↑/↓)" needs qualification.

While these characters are not defined in the [American Standard Code for Information Interchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) as glyphs, their codes WERE commonly used to give a graphical presentation for ASCII codes 24 and 25 (hex 18 and 19, CANcel and EM:End of Medium). [Code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) (called Extended ASCII by IBM, includes the numeric codes 128 to 255) defined the use of these glyphs as ASCII codes and the ubiquity of these conventions permeated the industry as seen by their deployment as standards by leading companies such as HP, particularly for printers, and IBM, particularly for microcomputers starting with the original PC.

Just as the use of the ASCII codes for CAN and EM was relatively obsolete at the time, justifying their use as glyphs, so has the passage of time made the use of the codes as glyphs obsolete by the current use of UNICODE conventions.

---

It should be emphasized that the extensions to ASCII made by IBM in Extended ASCII, included not only a larger numeric set for numeric codes 128 to 255, but also extended the use of some numeric control codes, in the ASCII range 0 to 32, from just media transmission control protocols to include glyphs.  It is often assumed, incorrectly, that the first 0 to 128 were not "extended" and that IBM was using the glyphs of conventional ASCII for this range. This error is also perpetrated in one of the previous references. This error became so pervasive that it colloquially redefined ASCII subliminally.

Answer (score 13):

I know I'm late to the party but you can accomplish this with plain CSS as well:

**HTML:**

*(It can be any HTML element, if you're using an inline element like a `<span>` for example, make sure you make it a block/inline-block element with `display:block;` or `display:inline-block`)*:

`<div class="up"></div>`

and

`<div class="down"></div>`

**CSS:**

```
.up {
   height:0;
   width:0;
   border-top:100px solid black;
   border-left:100px solid transparent;
   transform:rotate(-45deg);   
  }

.down {
   height:0;
   width:0;
   border-bottom:100px solid black;
   border-right:100px solid transparent;
   transform:rotate(-45deg); 
  }
```

You can also accomplish it using `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, which is actually a better way since you avoid creating extra markup. But that's up to you on how you'd like to accomplish it.

--

Here's a **[Demo in CodePen](http://codepen.io/rzea/pen/feiLs)** with many arrow possibilities.

Comment: While it is nice to be able to do this in pure CSS, there are some issues such as lack of shading support in Firefox or IE, after hours wasted, I'm back to Unicode arrows

Comment: @direct00 You're missing the point. If you know you're styling your arrows a certain way, you would know off the bat which method is best for your needs. If you wasted your time, it's not my solution's problem, is yours. And no need for that attitude either. Good luck.

Answer (score 12):

A lot of people here are suggesting to use the triangles, but sometimes you need a chevron.

We had a case where our button shows a chevron, and wanted the user's manual to refer to the button in a way which will be recognized by a non-technical user too. So we needed a chevron sign.

We used  ﹀ in the end. It is known as PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET and its code is U+FE40.

Answer (score 11):

I think the asker may be referring to one of these (see attached image) - I found this StackOverflow question while searching for the same thing myself.

Unfortunately, this glyph doesn't seem to exist as a distinct character entity anywhere.  Wikipedia accomplishes it below by using inline javascript and img content="data:image/gif..." to achieve the symbol.

Incidentally, here's the base64 for it:

```
data:image/gif;base64,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
```

Hope this helps someone!
[image]

Comment: Oops, I just noticed that the asker said "up OR down" so nevermind, but still, some may find this "up AND down" useful to some degree..

Comment: The base64 option is a good addition to this thread. Good One.

Comment: Although the base64 string for a simple gif is excessively long. Ive compressed a sharper base64 image of the same icon down to 70 characters. I've added it to my answer above.

Comment: Is it able to customize the color?

Comment: jquery icon `ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s`, or `ui-icon-caret-2-n-s` .  But only 16 pixels x 16 pixels, unless you scale it with a transform.

Answer (score 10):

▲▼
These are U+25B2 (`&#x25B2`) and U+25BC (`&#x25BC`) respectively

Answer (score 10):

**HTML Entities for empty triangles**
◁ = `&#9665;` 
▷ = `&#9655;` 
▽ = `&#9661;` 
△ = `&#9651;`

Answer (score 5):

[This one](http://www.plcdev.com/ascii_chart) seems to imply that 030 and 031 are up and down triangles.

*(As bobince pointed out, this doesn't seem to be an ASCII standard)*

Comment: works for me. ...The link, not the characters; that's [Code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), not ASCII at all. 437 is an old DOS code page not usable in browsers.

Comment: I just tried "ALT-[NUMPAD 3]-[NUMPAD 1]" and got: ▼
(OS is Windows XP SP3, browser is Firefox 3.6(?)).

Answer (score 4):

I use ▼ and ▲, but they might not work for you.  I use alt 11551 for the first one and 11550 for the second one.  You can always copy paste them if the ascii isnt the same for your system.

Answer (score 2):

I decided that most popular symbols recommended here (▼ and ▲) are looking too bold, so on the site codepoints.net, recommended by user ADJenks, I found these symbols which are looking better for my taste:
 (U+1F780)  (U+1F781)  (U+1F782)  (U+1F783)

Comment: the  and  are certainly prettier, but they don't work in react native (at least in v0.59)

Answer (score 0):

The site I like to use for this is [codepoints.net](https://codepoints.net)

Here is a search for the words "arrowhead" and "triangle": https://codepoints.net/search?q=arrowhead+triangle

It has some matches for "triangle-headed arrow" that have stems, but it's only 4 small pages to skim over and there are many good matches with nice details on each character.

There is also a code block for "Miscellaneous Symbols and Arrows" and this website lists them here: https://codepoints.net/miscellaneous_symbols_and_arrows

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one - ᐞ - Unicode U+141E  / CANADIAN SYLLABICS GLOTTAL STOP

Answer (score 0):

**Unicode** arrows seem pretty much out, because as of 2021 Android phones do not seem to come installed with full Unicode fonts that contain arrows (simply most top language fonts, ie Chinese, Arabic, etc); and a webpage asking to download a decent Unicode font, such as Arial Unicode MS, will put a 22Meg hit on your download time.

**FontAwesome** is quite useful for these kinds of dingbats.  Version 4.7 font-awesome.min.css weighs in at 30KB. sort-up, sort-down, chevron-up, chevron-down provide your characters.  `https://fontawesome.com/v4.7/get-started/`  Works great in *regular* HTML (text, etc).  However it requires rewriting, and so inside *literal span contexts* is more tricky to use.

**jquery** already supports icons that people can use, by quietly downloading a 6.8K font image and then taking chunks out of it under the hood. Both carets (chevrons) and triangles (arrowheads).  See https://api.jqueryui.com/theming/icons/ for a catalog.  After including jquery, include a glyph by using code `<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n"></span>`.  The up and down arrows you requested are `ui-icon-caret-1-n` and `ui-icon-caret-1-s` (for north and south); the carets are better than triangles for looking pointy at low resolutions.  And they can be colorized.

Unfortunately, jquery currently appears hardwired to display icons at 16x16 pixel resolution--grain-of-sand on today's monitors.  They can be enlarged using the transform function.  But it starts to get sloppy.

jquery icons can also be hacked by locally overriding with your own image, through background:url().  See the jquery docs.

**Bytesize Icons** `https://github.com/danklammer/bytesize-icons` is not too bad.

there are others.