# How to show an arrow down symbol with CSS

Tags: css, unicode, fonts

I saw some nice styled dropdown boxes like this one and wanted to create my own one:

[image]

The CSS to create the arrow was quite simple. It just adds a unicode character as arrow as content to the :before class of an element;

```
.select:before{
    content: "\f0d7";
}
```

I tried it on my own, but the character is not shown, because the character is not contained in a default language like Arial:

http://jsfiddle.net/3cW9M/

I could of course include a font, that contains this character, but I think its to much overhead to add another ~100kb to the page just for the error.

Is there any other good solution to archive this arrow style without additional fonts or images?

Comment: see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701192/ascii-character-for-up-down-triangle-arrow-to-display-in-html

Comment: You could either use a CSS triangle, or one of these: http://jsfiddle.net/tUuSB/ .. a library isn't needed for a mere arrow.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You may use other [unicode](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=down%20triangle) or use borders :
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3cW9M/2/)**

```
.select:before{
    content: "\25be  or  \25bc  ?  ";
    float:right;
    color:gray;
}
.select:after{
    content: "";
    margin:0 0.5em;
    display:inline-block;
    border: 7px solid transparent;
    border-top:8px solid gray;
    border-bottom:0 none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `\25bc` instead.

And if you want to change the color just add css color property.

```
.select:before{
    content: "\25bc";
    color: gray;
}
```

Comment: i used "\25bc" , i got arrow icon. please tell me where can i find a documentation to learn more about this?

Answer (score 2):

All CSS method

```
 .arrow-down {
     height:0px;
     width:0px;
     border:none;
     border-top:5px solid #000000;
     border-left:5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
     border-right:5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2sU2x/2/

Comment: +1 I think that pure CSS is the best way to go. You could also do `transparent` instead of `rgba(0,0,0,0)`. This will work in older browsers that do not support the `rgba` CSS3 property. (i.e. `border-right: 5px solid transparent;`)

Comment: yes, you could do both so it degrades gracefully across browsers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use FontAwesome:

add this information into the `<head>` `</head>` section:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

then this CSS:

```
.select:after {
  content: "\f0da";
  float: right;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
```

caret-down   =  `"\f0d7"`
caret-up     =  `"\f0d8"`
caret-left   =  `"\f0d9"`
caret-right  =  `"\f0da"`

Answer (score 0):

Your estimate of 100kb is a bit off for that one arrow. You can compile fonts from just the symbols you need for your app, using for example http://icomoon.io/. I can, off hand, estimate that arrow would generate a font of about 1kB.

If you take into account all the little bits and pieces you want to include in your page, like say social plugin icons, navigation tidbits, user icons, action icons, et caetera, then the method you specify of including custom fonts in your page is pretty worth it, assuming you only include the glyphs you need!

Comment: I did not know that I can just compile a font with the characters I need. I will try that.