# Unicode character fallback?

Tags: android, html, css, mobile, unicode

Certain mobile browsers do not seem to support all unicode characters, like this down arrow icon:

```
span.icon:after {
    content:"\25be";
}
```

Simply nothing is displayed. How can I detect this and provide either fallback text or an image?

Comment: Can you specify which browsers failed?

Comment: If those mobile browsers support @font-face just add a custom font with such character in your font stack. Probably it's not a browser problem, maybe (simply) it does not have the gliph available...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about fallback, but you may want to try
    content:"\25bc"
(larger arrow)
instead of 
    content:"\25be"
It is said to be better supported.
See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/2701226