# What's the html code for the opposite version of &#9662;?

Tags: html

I'm looking for the opposite code for   `&#9662;` ▾

Small triangle pointing upwards. Couldn't find it in any list.

This is a print screen of one of the answers below, they look a bit different.
[image]

Comment: If you google "html code Small triangle pointing upwards", the top 3 links would give you a solution...

Comment: I did that. Did you find the solution if you're so sure?

Comment: my top 3 links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701192/character-for-up-down-triangle-arrow-to-display-in-html (see accepted answer), http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25b2/index.htm, http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25b4/index.htm - no offence, just pointing out

Comment: Consider selecting one answer if it helped you: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

▲

With code `&#9650;` or `&#x25b2;`

Want to know how I found it? I used my LaTeX editor TeXstudio. It unicode panel shows all symbols close to it, when you enter "x25b" or the symbol

Comment: That one is larger than OP's, though.

Comment: Guess then it is ▴, 0x25b4, 9652. They all look the same to me. Do not know how to get glasses in Germany

Comment: they are different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

`&#9662;` ▾ is U+25BE (BLACK DOWN-POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE), so what you want is U+25B4 (BLACK UP-POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE): `&#9652;` ▴

---

<sup><sup>http://r12a.github.io/uniview is my favourite tool for this.</sup></sup>

Comment: it's different size.

Comment: Are you sure? As per the Unicode standard they're the same size, and looking at them here they're the same for me. It could be the font you're using, have you tried a different one?

Comment: just look at them, don't they look different? What browser/OS are you using, maybe they get interpreted different.

Comment: Chrome on Debian, and they look the same size to me.

Comment: I added an image in the question how they look on my side.

Comment: Too bad. It's most likely a font issue, though. So if you're making your own website, you can use a font in which they look OK.

Comment: I'm going with font-awesome to make sure is showing the same to everyone. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this,
    `&#9652` ▴
thanks

Comment: it's different size.

Answer (score 0):

I googled the string on your question adding "Unicode":

```
Small triangle pointing upwards unicode
```

and got this as the first link:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25b4/index.htm

▴  (U+25B4)

HTML Entity (decimal)   `&#9652;`

Or you can search for "up triangle" in this site, and get this page:

http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=up+triangle