# How to know the corresponding Unicode of this character?

Tags: java, user-interface, unicode, character-encoding

I can not find the corresponding `unicode` of this character
I need it, to use in my `Java` application
[image]
I also searched more in some `unicode` tables, like following link
http://bulenkov.com/2012/10/14/arrow-symbols-in-java/
Also, searched in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) community
But no luck
So, generally How I can know the corresponding `unicode` of required character?

Comment: It might not be unicode, the app can just draw on a component if it wants to.

Comment: also doesn't look like unicode to me, but rather as a (graphical) dropdown icon. the best (pure) unicode match i see is `U+25BC` (triangle south) ...and maybe a [possible dupilcate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2701192/592355)

Comment: Could be U+2304 down arrowhead perhaps?

Comment: U+2228, U+23F7, U+2BC6, U+2B9F. This seems to be a simple matter of just taking the time to look these things up. https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.html

Comment: Can you select the character on the screen with the mouse? If so, you can copy it, save it into a text file and inspect the text file with a hex editor.

Comment: Thanks all, you are right, its seems not be unicode character!

Comment: @MrLister It is an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After check with UI/UX Team
Its already a drawable image not a `unicode` character

Thanks to @markspace @xerx593 comments

Answer (score 0):

There is a really simple method of doing that, that is, write a code to print all unicode characters and then search for it.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String\[\] args)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<=65536;x++)
        {
            System.out.println(x+"\t"+(char)x);
        }
    }
}
```

It is 9207.

Comment: Nightmare BRUTE FORCE solution :)

Comment: Unicode has over a hundred thousand characters, much more than 64K.