# How do i define chinese character in html

Tags: html

I am new to html, and i want to design a website in Chinese language, but in my editor the chinese characters are not supported, giving unsupported format for chinese language, included

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What characters can be used for up/down triangle (arrow without stem) for display in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701192/what-characters-can-be-used-for-up-down-triangle-arrow-without-stem-for-displa)

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 is a character encoding. UTF-8 is one of the most recent character encodings developed that supports all characters from the huge list known as Unicode. Unicode assigns a number called code point for each character that it recognises. The idea is similar to the A=65 mapping in ASCII. UTF-8 provides a way to represent these code points as bits, for the purpose of file storage or network transmission.

Use:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Or the long way

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```