# Rotate only the ::after content, not the whole element

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have the following CSS class which represents a **Tile** in a grid.

```
.col {
  background: #ffffff;
  user-select: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 25px;
  min-width: 25px;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid #afd8f8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #afd8f8;
}
```

I later on add the following CSS class with JavaScript to the **Tile**, this CSS class represents a **Player**:

```
.player {
  position: relative;
  &::after {
    z-index: 99;
    content: "";
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    position: relative;
    background: url(./../assets/player.svg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

Here is the player.svg:

[image: player.svg]

A **Tile** div that contains the player ends up looking like this:

```
<div class="col player">< /div>
```

I would like to animate the player so that when he goes up he rotates **-90deg**.

I'm trying to add this functionality with JavaScript but it seems that I'm rotating the whole div (messing up some of my game logic). I'm looking forward to only rotating the **Player** not the whole div.

I've tried the following:

```
grid[i][j].DOMElement.style.transform = 'rotate(-90deg)';
```

> grid[i][j].DOMElement returns the **HTMLElement** for a specific
> **Tile**.

But as I said before this rotates the entire div...

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701192/what-characters-can-be-used-for-up-down-triangle-arrow-without-stem-for-displa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably easiest to add a class to the parent, and use that to modify the `::after`

```
.player {
  position: relative;
  &::after {
    z-index: 99;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    position: relative;
    background: url(./../assets/player.svg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  &.rotated::after {
    transform: rotate(-90deg)
  }
}

grid[i][j].DOMElement.classList.add("rotated")
```